# Redirect localhost/dashboard

Tags: php

I have a problem with my personal site (using xampp);, any time I perform a log out when an imaginary user is alrealy logged in, I am redirected to the localhost/dashboard. Could you kindly say me how to solve?

Here is my 'logout' code:

```
<?php   /** --- logout.php --- **/
    require_once 'createSession.php';
    require_once 'https.php';

    if(!isset($loggedIn) || (!$loggedIn)) {
        $result = "<h2>You are not logged in!</h2>";
        if(isset($TimeoutExpired) && ($TimeoutExpired))
            $result = $result."<p>Timeout expired! You have not interacted with our server for too much time!</p>";
    }
    else {
        destroySession();
        echo "<h2>You have been successfully logged out.</h2>";
        $goodbye = true;
    }

    $loggedIn = false;
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Where 'index.php' is my main page and it is in the same folder of this file
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the contents of createSession.php and https.php just for better understanding of the code ?

Comment: Where is the code ot perform the redirect to the dashboard?

Comment: I actually want to redirect to my personal page, that is index.php. It's all in my folder, but I don't know why it redirects to localhost/dashboard.

Comment: Could it be that you have some redirection to ``/dashboard`` in either the application itself or on the level of the http protocol, so configured in the http server configuration (maybe a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"))?

Comment: move your index.php to a folder inside htacess/wamp folder